# Ruby on Rails Event Machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine

Where is the proper place to place eventmachine code in a rails app?

For example:

```
class Test < EventMachine::Connection
  def post_init
    send_data "test"
  end

  def receive_data(data)
  end
end

EventMachine.run {
  EventMachine.connect "someplace.com", 80, Test
}
```

Now say I required this for one of my controllers my app will just continue waiting while this runs.

How can I have this run in the background in a rails app?

Comment: Are you running Rails with an EM based webserver like [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) or [Rainbows!](http://rainbows.rubyforge.org/)?

Comment: This answer may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799406/how-do-you-spawn-an-eventmachine-inside-a-rails-app

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect solution for that. It depends on how you designed your app.

You could put this code in /lib, have a method "start_event_machine" and call this method in a rake task. Then add stuff like [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) on your server to make sure it runs fine.

Comment: After calling the method in a rake task would it keep running?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into either [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) or [DelayedJob](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) for backgrounding tasks.  I don't think that EventMachine is the best solution for trying to background jobs within Ruby on Rails.

The other option is to have a separate process for handling the async work, passing the task down a message queue like RabbitMQ or something similar.

Comment: How do you start a job? For example, I create test.rb. How do I start that?