# Faye in jruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, real-time, faye

I have searched A LOT and couldn't find any resource that says I can use Faye with jruby. I have found [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/faye-users/wvp_K38vTpo) that says that it doen't play well with jruby but it's really really old. Also I have found [this](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2012/08/02/your-first-ruby-native-extension-java/) that looks like they have implemented a Java native extension in order to support jruby?? Does anyone know if I can use it in a Jruby on rails project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the creator of Faye:

> Yes, the server runs on JRuby. The client uses either WebSocket, EventSource, XMLHttpRequest, CORS or JSON-P depending on what is supported by the user's browser, the server, and the intervening network, and is compatible with other Bayeux servers.